# error in ajax chat web application,index.php won't show anything

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have a problem with ajax chat, i just installed it and did the changes to the config.php file, by filling in the names of the host, database, username etc. when i go the index.php file on my browser, all i get is: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

and then after the message, nothing is displayed, the rest of the page is blank. this looks like an error message made by the developer of the script, because i opened the index.php file and came across:

```
// Show all errors:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

has anyone out there come across a similar problem, how did you fix it? like step by step, i've checked the web but there seems to be no legitimate answer. i kindly ask for assistance from anyone who can help me to fix this error, and maybe tell me why it showed up, thanks in advance. here is the url: (http: / / sourceforge . net / projects / ajax - chat /) of where to find it(remove extra spaces and brackets), incase someone may be unfamiliar with it, the readme file gives a step by step guide on how to install it. thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be an error, check you apache error logs.

Comment: There is little sense asking for help about "some thing you installed". Tell what you installed, a link or something, so that other can verify the problem.

Comment: yes, i've given the url for the site in the question.